# How to force clear cache for dynamic url in Fat-free Framework?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

How do i clear the cache of my patterned url (dynamic url)?
Like, `/assets/js/@jsname.js`...
I don't want to wait until the cache expired, i want to it, immediately after i updated things on my database.

[They said](http://fatfreeframework.com/cache#clear) that to clear the database, you need to specify the key for it. And i don't know what should i enter for the key :(

Here's my code:

```
\F3::route("GET @virtualasset: /assets/img/@link/@size.@id.@type", "Control\\Imager->akses", 3600 * 24 * 7); // cache seminggu :3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP responses are cached using the following [key](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/blob/3223f33c2bb7a45ac98c93bd8949997ea5bd9bb0/base.php#L1473): `hash(VERB URI).url`.

So if you want to refresh `assets/js/foo.js`, you'll have to do:

```
$hash=$f3->hash('GET /assets/js/foo.js');
$cache->clear($hash.'.url');
```

But that's a bit of a hack since this key is not documented and may change in the future.

Also you need to remember that the route `$ttl` parameter not only triggers server cache but also client cache. Which means that you need to implement a cache buster to refresh the client cache. Something like `assets/js/foo.js?v=3`.

You may consider implementing cache directly in your controller class. That would give you more flexibility.

Comment: woah! okay... I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

I use this route:

> GET|HEAD /assets/@folder/@type/v-@version/* = controllers\Assets->send, 3600

My controller:

```
namespace controllers;
class Assets {

    private $paths;
    private $types = ['css', 'js', 'i', 'fonts', 'files', 'icons'];
    private $dontminify = ['i', 'fonts', 'files', 'icons'];


    public function __construct() {
        $this->fw = \Base::instance();
        $this->paths['app'] =  '../app/views/site_tpl/assets/';
        $this->paths['core'] = '../core/views/default/assets/';
    }

    public function send() {

        if (in_array($this->fw->get('PARAMS.folder'), array_keys($this->paths))
            && in_array($this->fw->get('PARAMS.type'), $this->types))
        {
            $folder = $this->paths[$this->fw->get('PARAMS.folder')];
            $type = $this->fw->get('PARAMS.type');
            if (in_array($type, $this->dontminify)) {
                $file = $folder . $type . '/' . $this->fw->pop('PARAMS');
                if (\Web::instance()->send($file)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                $this->fw->set('UI', $folder . $type . '/');
                $file = $this->fw->pop('PARAMS');
                if (file_exists($this->fw->get('UI') . $file)) {
                    if (!$this->fw->exists('GET.dontminify')) {
                        echo \Web::instance()->minify($file);
                        return true;
                    } elseif (\Web::instance()->send($this->fw->get('UI') . $file)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $this->fw->error(404);
    }

}
```

So, when I want to update version of file, I write somethong like this:

```
<script src="/assets/app/js/v-20160205/main.js"></script>
```